Classification of rank one non-compact symmetric spaces
The list of all compact rank one symmetric spaces up to isometry is $ \mathbb{R}P^n=SO(n+1)/O(n) $, $ S^n=SO(n+1)/SO(n) $, $  \mathbb{C}P^n= SU(n+1)/U(n) $, $ \mathbb{H}P^n=Sp(n+1)/(Sp(n) \times Sp(1)) $ and the Octonionic projective plane $ Spin(9)/F_4 $.
Is there a nice classification of non compact rank one symmetric spaces? Besides $ \mathbb{R}^1 $ are there also 3 families of noncompact and one exceptional?

Of course. For questions of this type the first place you should look in is Helgason's book. If it is insufficiently detailed for you, then Mostow's book.
